# How to catch youtube video player's Play/Pause event using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make callback after play button is pushed - Youtube embed video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152814/make-callback-after-play-button-is-pushed-youtube-embed-video)

I have a Youtube video embeded on my website. The code is as below

```
<iframe width="280" height="180" frameborder="0" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/U5BVeZybEV4" title="YouTube video player"  allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

What I want to do is, when I click on **Play** button of the Video, it should execute a javascript alert function as

```
alert("Clicked Play");
```

Same way, if I click on Pause button, it should execute a javascript alert function as

```
alert("Clicked Pause");
```

Any suggestion how can I catch these Events ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152814/make-callback-after-play-button-is-pushed-youtube-embed-video

Answer (score 1):

Check this example below, we can do it using Youtube Player API

http://jsfiddle.net/masiha/4mEDR/

Comment: Hi aslamdoctor, Thanks for using my jsfiddle to answer . :)

Comment: Here is updated version of the **jsfiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/7Gznb/2150/